# jsPDF add chart

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to generate PDF documents through Appcelerator's Titanium. Now i need to add a simple pie chart with two segments. How could i do that in simplest way?

It doesn't need to be anything fancy. I am thinking about generating an image first, and add that image to the document. Maybe there's a library that could generate images of pie-chart's and save it to the phone. However, im not sure about jsPDF's support of images, i can't seem to find any good documentation of the library.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you integrated jspdf in titanium.

Answer (score 10):

I know it has been inactive for almost a year, but since it doesn't have an accepted answer, I'll try to answer.

**Adding chart to jsPDF**

1.Convert chart to supported image format (JPEG or PNG encoded in base64) using HTML Canvas.

2.Make sure the image URL available to the addImage function.

Below is an example to add image to jsPDF doc without having to include raw base64 code. It is taken from jsPDF example.

```
function demoImages() {
    // Because of security restrictions, getImageFromUrl will
    // not load images from other domains.  Chrome has added
    // security restrictions that prevent it from loading images
    // when running local files.  Run with: chromium --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access
    // to temporarily get around this issue.
    var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
        var img = new Image(), data, ret = {
            data: null,
            pending: true
        };

        img.onError = function() {
            throw new Error('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
        };
        img.onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            // Grab the image as a jpeg encoded in base64, but only the data
            data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);
            // Convert the data to binary form
            data = atob(data);
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);

            ret['data'] = data;
            ret['pending'] = false;

            console.log("data",data);

            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(data);
            }
        };
        img.src = url;

        return ret;
    };

    // Since images are loaded asyncronously, we must wait to create
    // the pdf until we actually have the image data.
    // If we already had the jpeg image binary data loaded into
    // a string, we create the pdf without delay.
    var createPDF = function(imgData) {
        var doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 50, 50);
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 70, 10, 100, 120);

        doc.save('output.pdf');

    }

    getImageFromUrl('thinking-monkey.jpg', createPDF);
}
```

**Good Documentation of jsPDF**

You will learn a lot of jsPDF features from their *[practical documentation](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/basic.html)*. For example source code, don't download from GitHub, because some files are missing. You can download from [here](http://www.teedim.com/js/parall.ax/jspdf/jsPDF-0.9.0rc2.zip).

**note**:remove semicolon on the 312th line of basic.js to make the code works.

Cheers,...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can check the [jsPDF](http://jspdf.com/) site first, you can generate you image with a library (perhaps google chart), save the chart as image and then add to the PDF, using the plugin `jspdf.plugin.addimage.js` and some code.
This is an [example](http://jspdf.com/) taken from their web site

```
var imgData = 'here the jpeg image string on base64';
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
```